# Prometheus & Micrometer : custom timestamp

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am writing a program in Java with SpringBoot, using Micrometer for Prometheus. I am using counter method. I was wondering if there was a way to inject custom timestamp into Prometheus with (or even without) micrometer library?

I am new to Prometheus, and I've read some articles making me think that it is possible to set a custom timestamp, such as:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/ the timestamp exposition format
- https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/Collector.java the collector registry. Should I use this one with a Pushgateway or on its own? How does it work? I didn't manage to find a lot of information about it.

I don't really understand how to use all of this, and which direction should I take.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why do you want a custom timestamp? Timestamps should only be used in very limited circumstances, and a normal counter is not one of them.

Comment: Hi,
I hope it won't be too vague : I would like to collect and store Hyperledger Fabrics metrics in Prometheus. 
When you listen to transaction events, you gather all the passed events as well. I would like to inject to prometheus the transaction events timestamp instead of the current time. This would allow me to have the complete view on my blockchain events metrics.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That sounds like event logging, for which Prometheus is not suited. Try Loki or the ELK stack.

Comment: Okay, I see! Thank you very much for your help. :)